# techniques to deploy web application: heroku vs in house vs vps ect ect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web, deployment, cloud

I'm looking for a document that explains the techniques to make the deployment of web applications: in the cloud, in-house, in housing ect ect ... 
For every technique I would like to know the pros and cons, so I do a general idea.

I searched online but have not found anything really comprehensive and interesting.

Can you help me?

Comment: No, there is no opinion. I need a document that explain the pros and the cons in a scientific way

Comment: I'll give you some pointers, but they're opinions based on facts

Comment: This blog of mine will give you some (basic) pointers, though it not an exhaustive document as you expect: http://notingon.com/2014/02/07/your-cloud-platform-iaas-paas-and-the-providers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Apps**

Web apps all have the same structure -- series of files running on a server "stack", accessed sequentially from middleware, or framework-based load structure

Your question, therefore, is more about which stack is going to be most scaleable, efficient, robust & expansive (can add extra resources). Here are the options:

---

**Heroku**

- "Managed" cloud (environment already set up)
- Runs off AWS instances
- Versatile (runs any gem / app)
- [Owned by Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/uk/heroku/)
- Lots of add-ons
- Highly scalable
- Not sure about price
- Easy deployment (`git push heroku master`)

---

**Cloud (AWS / Rackspace)**

- "Full" cloud
- You're responsible for environment (OS, gems, ruby ver etc)
- You're responsible for uptime
- You have to maintain db etc yourself
- Scaling can be a pain in the ass
- Can deploy your app in a totally bespoke environment
- Performance likely won't be issue (have 100's of servers to pool from)

---

**VPS**

- "Shared" hosting
- Have to install environment yourself
- Very tricky to keep gems / ruby / rails up to date
- Have to maintain the db etc yourself
- Not many companies actually offer decent VPS
- Costs more than Heroku
- Not very scaleable
- If someone else causes issues on the server, your app gets hit too

We use Heroku for all "baby" apps - AWS / Rackspace for apps with growth

Comment: Three points: (1) Heroku pricing is here: https://www.heroku.com/pricing; (2) with the addition of 2X and PX dynos (dedicated hardware, 8 core, and 6G RAM), Heroku is suitable for any type of app. Even computationally intensive apps (3) AWS has a many additional services that integrate with EC2 (e.g., Amazon RDS, S3, AutoScaling) so no need to run your own DB and scaling in pretty easy.